# What's the difference between "ein bisschen" and "manchmal"

Tags: adverb

I just wanted to know what's the difference between *ein bisschen* and *manchmal*? When and where should I use each? Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Manchmal* talks about times of occurrence so it measures a countable thing. It answers the questions

> When?   - Nie, manchmal, oft, immer
>
> How often? - Einmal, zweimal, dreimal, manchmal

*ein bisschen* talks about a quantity of uncountable things or characteristics without being limited to a certain domain. It answers to the questions

> How much?  - wenig Zeit, ein bisschen Zeit, viel Zeit
>
> How intense? - gar nicht laut, ein bisschen laut, sehr laut

They are never interchangeable because one talks about countable and the other about uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

Manchmal = sometimes, ein bisschen = a little bit.